# How to display content based on selection in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

I have two component Horizontal Tab Component and Vertical Side Bar Component and both the component are merged in single component i.e. in Combined.js

My Vertical Side Bar Component state contain array of object i.e `const [items, setitems] = useState({
    stude: [{ displayid: "12", name: "CHRIS" }, { displayid: "13", name: "RYAN" }]
  });`

How can i display content on the Horizontal Tab Selected on the basis of selected option from Vertical Side Bar Component using react-bootstrap.

**Now the main problem is I want to pass my `displayid` to horizontal tab Component, for the selected   Vertical Side Bar Component i am stuck in in this section**

Quick demo its not working allthough because of fake url https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-violet-063pg?file=/App.js

Comment: The example is not working.

Comment: hi @Abdelrhman Arnos  I know its not working the main problem is I want to pass my displayid to horizontal tab Component, for the selected Vertical Side Bar Component i am stuck in in this section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a `useState` in the **combined** component and pass the setter to the **Vertical** component to set the `id` *onSelect* then pass the `id` you get to the **Horizontal**. Here you can check an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-pine-yy5g9?file=/src/Combined.js:275-285).

Comment: Thanks a lot bro , i was confused on this part you made a way that clears it.